# Geodesic equations and carter constant: how can I derive the right equations?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, orbital-motion, geodesics

### Introduction

Suppose the Hamilton-Jacobi equation:

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial \lambda} + \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial S}{\partial x^{\mu}}\frac{\partial S}{\partial x^{\nu}}= 0. \tag{1}$$

Now, consider the ansatz (for null geodesics):

$$S = -Et+L\phi+S_{r}(r)+S_{\theta}(\theta)\tag{2}.$$

Furthermore, consider de metric:

$$ds^{2} = -A(r)dt^{2}+B(r)^{-1}dr^{2}+r^{2}d\theta^{2}+r^{2}sin^{2}(\theta)d\phi^{2}. \tag{3}$$

Plugging equation $(2)$ in $(1)$, we reach on:

$$-E\dot{t}+L\dot{\phi}+\partial_{\lambda}S_{r}(r)+\partial_{\lambda}S_{\theta}(\theta)+\frac{1}{2}\Bigg\{g^{00}\Bigg[\Bigg(\partial_{0}(-Et+L\phi+S_{r}(r)+S_{\theta}(\theta))\Bigg)^{2}\Bigg]+ g^{11}\Bigg[\Bigg(\partial_{1}(-Et+L\phi+S_{r}(r)+S_{\theta}(\theta))\Bigg)^{2}\Bigg]+g^{22}\Bigg[\Bigg(\partial_{2}(-Et+L\phi+S_{r}(r)+S_{\theta}(\theta))\Bigg)^{2}\Bigg]+g^{33}\Bigg[\Bigg(\partial_{3}(-Et+L\phi+S_{r}(r)+S_{\theta}(\theta))\Bigg)^{2}\Bigg]\Bigg\} = 0 \iff$$

$$\iff -E\dot{t}+L\dot{\phi}+\partial_{\lambda}S_{r}(r)+\partial_{\lambda}S_{\theta}(\theta)+\frac{1}{2}\Bigg\{g^{00}\Bigg[\partial_{0}(-Et)^{2}\Bigg]+ g^{11}\Bigg[(\partial_{1}(S_{r}(r))^{2}\Bigg]+g^{22}\Bigg[(\partial_{2}(S_{\theta}(\theta)))^{2}\Bigg]+g^{33}\Bigg[(\partial_{3}(L\phi))^{2}\Bigg]\Bigg\} = 0 \iff$$

> $$-E\dot{t}+L\dot{\phi}+\partial_{\lambda}S_{r}(r)+\partial_{\lambda}S_{\theta}(\theta)+\frac{1}{2}\Bigg\{A(r)^{-1}E^{2}+ B(r)(\partial_{1}(S_{r}(r))^{2}+r^{-2}(\partial_{2}(S_{\theta}(\theta)))^{2}+r^{-2}sin^{-2}(\theta)L^{2}\Bigg\} = 0  \tag{4}.$$

Knowing that the null geodesics are the well-known:

$$\dot{t} = \frac{E}{A(r)} \tag{5},$$

$$\dot{\phi} = \frac{L}{r^{2}sin^{2}(\theta)} \tag{6};$$

plugging $(5)$, $(6)$, in $(4)$, we reach in:

$$-E\Biggr(\frac{E}{A(r)}\Biggr)+L\Biggr(\frac{L}{r^{2}sin^{2}(\theta)}\Biggr)+\partial_{\lambda}S_{r}(r)+\partial_{\lambda}S_{\theta}(\theta)+\frac{1}{2}\Bigg\{A(r)^{-1}E^{2}+ B(r)(\partial_{1}(S_{r}(r))^{2}+r^{-2}(\partial_{2}(S_{\theta}(\theta)))^{2}+r^{-2}sin^{-2}(\theta)L^{2}\Bigg\} = 0  \iff$$

$$-\frac{E^2}{A(r)}+\frac{L^2}{r^{2}sin^{2}(\theta)}+\partial_{\lambda}S_{r}(r)+\partial_{\lambda}S_{\theta}(\theta)+\frac{1}{2}A(r)^{-1}E^{2}+ \frac{1}{2}B(r)(\partial_{1}(S_{r}(r))^{2}+\frac{1}{2}r^{-2}(\partial_{2}(S_{\theta}(\theta)))^{2}+\frac{1}{2}r^{-2}sin^{-2}(\theta)L^{2} = 0  \iff$$

$$-\frac{2E^2}{A(r)}+\frac{2L^2}{r^{2}sin^{2}(\theta)}+A(r)^{-1}E^{2}+ B(r)(\partial_{1}(S_{r}(r))^{2}+r^{-2}(\partial_{2}(S_{\theta}(\theta)))^{2}+r^{-2}sin^{-2}(\theta)L^{2} = 0  \iff$$

> $$-\frac{E^2}{A(r)}+\frac{3L^2}{r^{2}sin^{2}(\theta)}+B(r)(\partial_{1}(S_{r}(r))^{2}+r^{-2}(\partial_{2}(S_{\theta}(\theta)))^{2} = 0  \tag{7}$$

### My Question

The carter constant, $\mathcal{K}$, appears as a separation constant when:

> $$(\partial_{2}(S_{\theta}(\theta)))^{2} + \frac{3L^2}{sin^{2}(\theta)} = -r^2 B(r)(\partial_{1}(S_{r}(r))^{2} + \frac{r^2 E^2}{A(r)} = \mathcal{K}.  \tag{8}$$

Knowing that, $\frac{\partial S_{r}}{\partial r} = p_{r} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{r}} = \frac{1}{B(r)}\dot{r}$ and $\frac{\partial S_{\theta}}{\partial \theta} = p_{\theta} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\theta}} = r^2\dot{\theta}$, the separated equations becomes:

> $$\frac{1}{B(r)}\dot{r}^2 = \frac{E^2}{A(r)}- \frac{\mathcal{K}}{r^2} \tag{9}$$
>
> $$ r^4\dot{\theta}^2 = \mathcal{K} - \frac{3L^2}{sin^{2}(\theta)}.  \tag{10}$$

**Concerning the equation $(9)$, everthing is fine. But the last equation, $(10)$, with that 3 factor is killing my sanity, since in the papers the right result is just $r^4\dot{\theta}^2 = \mathcal{K} - \frac{L^2}{sin^{2}(\theta)}$. So, I would like to ask: why that constant "3" appeared in equation $(10)$?**